# How to set selected item of ListView without scrolling the view [Android]

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with 10 items in it, when i set the 4th item in the ListView as selected then my `ListView` gets scrolled and 4th item in the `ListView` gets placed at the top of the screen.

I don't want to scroll the `ListView` when i call `setSelected()` for the list item which is not in the view.

I have also tried to scroll the `ListView` programmatically using `scrollTo(0, 0);` but it is not working.

Comment: List_View.setSelection(Position); .. are use u set default value in listview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set position in ListView without scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374894/programmatically-set-position-in-listview-without-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hardcoded and thus not possible without scrolling

Comment: well that sucks big time.

Comment: look for http://stackoverflow.com/a/23688815/2835239. you can update data, change selection, and nothing will be scrolled. (actually  it not really selection. this is checked.)

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but it may be useful to somebody. You can use [setSelectionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int)). It's rather smart, and you can use it for example like that:

```java
getListView().setSelectionFromTop(selection, getListView().getHeight() / 2);
```

It begins to scroll only after middle of the list:

[image: setSelectionFromTop]

Comment: it will also scroll the list, to make it in the view.

Comment: You have to add more logic to achieve no scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

```
int top = listView.getChildAt(fixedChildIndex).getTop();

//set selected item, keep scroll position
listView.setSelectionFromTop(newIndex, top);
```

This keeps the ListViews Child with view index (ListView reuses views!) fixedChildIndex in place.

For example if you want the highlighting to stay use this:

```
int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int fixedChildIndex = listView.getSelectedItemPosition() - first;
View newSelectedChild = listView.getChildAt(selectedViewIndex);
```

If you want to make sure the selected item is fully visible use this line

```
//set selected item, keep scroll position and make sure it is completely visible
listView.setSelectionFromTop(newIndex, Math.min(Math.max(0,top), listView.getHeight()-newSelectedChild.getHeight()));
```

Where newSelectedChild is the view of the child you want to select. You can get it by doing this:

Answer (score 1):

you can use listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); option with

```
mListView.setItemChecked(pos, true);
```

Setup some selectors may be required. Also look for google example [IOSchedule App](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/) --great example about listview with multi selection controller (have a few bugs :) )

Comment: Then probably you use custom onClickListener. Have you checked google io example? it's works good

Answer (score 0):

`setSelection()` may be of your work.

Comment: Currently i am using setSelection and it is scrolling the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use setSelection()!

I do that in another way.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener oiclFolders = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int posi, long id) {
        // clear original selected item
        if ( mViewOrg!=null ) mViewOrg.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        if ( view!=null ) {
            // define your own drawable to set as background
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_bg);
            mViewOrg = view;
        }
        curSel = posi;    // to store which one is selected
        // Do NOT setSelection -> will auto scroll to top
        // mlvFolders.setSelection(posi);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

1. Set CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE when setting up the custom listview -
2. Use setSelected() inside OnItemClickListener() as under  -

   ```
   private void setup_view(View rootView) {
       listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
       if(listview != null) {
           listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
           listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
           listview.setOnItemClickListener(onitemclicklistener);
       }
   }

   private OnItemClickListener onitemclicklistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
               long id) {
             v.setSelected(true);
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `requestChildRectangleOnScreen` like this to get rid of the scrolling:

```
 @Override
    public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rectangle, boolean immediate) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `setSelection(4)` to set the Selection without scrolling if the new selection is visible.

Comment: Currently i am using setSelection and it is scrolling the list view.