# Android ListView setSelection without scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

If a `ListView` contains 30 items and maximum visible items are 6.
And, current cursor is at position 16 (visible items are 14~19). Now, I use `setSelection` to set the cursor to 18, and the cursor will move to item 18. But, the item 18 will be scrolled to the top of the `ListView`. How can I `setSelection` to other visible items without scrolling?

Comment: `setSelection` is a method to scroll, impossible with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set selected item of ListView without scrolling the view \[Android\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872647/how-to-set-selected-item-of-listview-without-scrolling-the-view-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can call smoothScrollTo(int position) to the item you want to scroll to. If you don't want that item to be at the top then just smoothScrollTo the item before that position.

Comment: Or simply use what you're using at the moment; `setSelection` but set the selection to the previous index so it does not go to the top?

Comment: no,  it will go to the top too if selection to the previous index